# What is the scope of git remote set-url command?

Tags: git

What is the scope of `git remote set-url` command?

Is it applicable for present git repo only or is it universal for the computer (so applicable to all repos on this computer)?

Answer (score 1):

[`git remote set-url`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote#Documentation/git-remote.txt-emset-urlem) is only for the current repository.

And only if said current repository already had a remote.
If you are adding a new remote, as opposed to modifying the URL of an existing remote, the command would be:

```sh
cd /path/to/local/repos
git remote add <newRemote> <url>
git remote add <newRemote> <url>|grep remote
```

You can list all configuration and their scopes with:

```sh
cd /path/to/local/repo
git config -l --show-origin --show-scope
git config -l --show-origin --show-scope|grep remote
```

The last command (with `grep`) would show only "`local`" scope for `remote`.

```
local   file:.git/config        remote.origin.url=...
```